# MySQL ; Best data type for large numbers

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

I want to store a field which stores channel clicks per day( **increasing every second and updated in a day**) into **MySQL** DB table. What datatype should I assign to the column keeping in mind that it can even be **less than 100** or can even **exceed a million**.

Comment: If it is an integer value - what is wrong with using an integer column. For value ranges see the documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MySQL [Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html):

[image]

[Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - DECIMAL, NUMERIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html):

> In standard SQL, the syntax DECIMAL(M) is equivalent to DECIMAL(M,0).
>   Similarly, the syntax DECIMAL is equivalent to DECIMAL(M,0), where the
>   implementation is permitted to decide the value of M. MySQL supports
>   both of these variant forms of DECIMAL syntax. The default value of M
>   is 10.
>
> If the scale is 0, DECIMAL values contain no decimal point or
>   fractional part.
>
> The maximum number of digits for DECIMAL is 65, but the actual range
>   for a given DECIMAL column can be constrained by the precision or
>   scale for a given column. When such a column is assigned a value with
>   more digits following the decimal point than are permitted by the
>   specified scale, the value is converted to that scale. (The precise
>   behavior is operating system-specific, but generally the effect is
>   truncation to the permissible number of digits.)

[Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html):

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Like we use varchar for indeterminate length string, Can I use this data type (DECIMAL) for  indeterminate number?

Comment: You need to be realistic about your real need. If you think you reach a million, well an `unsigned` int is 4000 times larger for its max. And only 4 bytes, and thin for joins.

Comment: `DECIMAL` does have a limit, but it is much higher than any possible 'counter'.